# Nibbling bytes in C

Tags: c, file, buffer

I need to nibble 4 bytes at a time in C.

Does C's read function buffer for me, i.e. read a 2^n-sized block from the file into a buffer and then read from that?

Or should I create my own buffer to read out of?

Comment: C does not guarantee anything about read buffers. If you want a buffer of a specific size, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: If you prefer to use `<stdio.h>` streams (rather than UNIXy "file descriptors"), you can use [setvbuf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) to assign buffering.

Comment: setvbuf was pretty much what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `uint32_t` buffer and read into that in chunks.  4096 bytes often works well as it is a good fraction of a block size, and a single memory page.  Then you can pull out a 32-bit word at a time, and use bitwise operators to extract each of the 4 bytes.

Very roughly speaking, something like:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

// Allocate buffer and open input file

uint32_t* buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

int fd = open(...);

// Loop while not end-of-file and read chunks

size_t bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

//...

// Process each chunk

unsigned word_count = bytes_read/sizeof(uint32_t);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
{
    uint32_t word = buffer[i];

    process(word);
}
```

If you need to address each byte by name, you could also create a union of 4 bytes with the `uint32_t`.